# Golang port blocking (?) using http.ListenAndServe

Tags: http, go, port

I have a simple golang program which listens for activity on a port before executing a function called *testFunc*

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/test", testFunc)
    http.ListenAndServe(":1337", nil)
}
```

When I build this program, run it and go to http://localhost:1337/test, it works fine.

When I terminate the program and try and run it again, the program instantly terminates showing no error output.

When I then change the port to 1338 for example, it works the first time, then fails each time after. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue… Can you try to disable your firewall / open these ports?

Comment: check the error from `http.ListenAndServe`

Comment: "showing no error output"… no crap, you didn't capture and show it! **Never** ignore error returns in any Go code.

Comment: BTW, the error is likely due to your operating system needing to hold the resources for the port for a while until old (possibly incompletely/incorrectly closed) connections fully expire.

Comment: Thanks all. Printing the error returns "listen tcp :1339: bind: address already in use". So i guess i need to kill the process or...?

Comment: Search for `EADDRINUSE`

Comment: Sorted, see answer for lols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port is most likely in use. Catching the error will give you more details.

```
if err := http.ListenAndServe(":1337", nil);err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
}
```

Comment: Since `ListenAndServe` (and `Serve`) don't normally return, this is often simplified to just `log.Fatalln("ListenAndServe:", http.ListenAndServe(":1337", nil))` or even just `log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":1337", nil))`. If Serve would return a `nil` error (it never does, but the documentation doesn't promise it) this would log "<nil>" but that's often what would be desired: some log entry when the server terminates.

Answer (score 1):

Ok turns out the error was my silly mistake. I have today switched from using a PC to Mac and didn't realise that Ctrl+C killed the current command instead of Ctrl+z which simply returns to shell... Therefore the processes were still running and blocking each other